# Using space instead of comma for large numbers?

Tags: formatting, siunitx

Is there a package I could use to insert a space instead of a comma for large numbers?

For example,

> 12 345.67

instead of

> 12,345.67

If needed, I am using the `extbook` environment. All of my numbers are in math mode.

**Edit**: Is there a way I can do this formatting without having to type in `num` (from `siunitx`) for every single number?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Numbers can be formatted with package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num{12345.67}  
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The space can be configured via option `group-separator`. Its default is a small space (`\,`).

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without manually typing `\num` prior to each number?

Comment: @Clarinetist: Package `siunitx` provides column type `S` for numbers inside tables. Otherwise digits would have to be made active. This cannot be done without breaking many other things, because numbers are used in many circumstances (`\hspace{2em}`, `\multicolumn{4}{...}{...}`, ...)

Comment: @Clarinetist: In some contexts (like a `tabular`, in a number-only column, say), yes. In general, not really.